# Q: Notify and write to Gatt Characteristic

Tags: ios, react-native, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon, beacon

I'm developing an application using react-native. I need to read and write to ble devices. For this I've chosen the **react-native-ble-plx** library. I'm supposed to notify my characteristic and then write to it packages of 20 bytes. My device is supposed to respond with either a success value or an error (including invalid command). The problem is that my device is not doing anything and i get no response. My code looks like this:

```
device.monitorCharacteristicForService('service_id', 'char_id', (error, characteristic) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  else {
    console.log(characteristic.value)
  }
})
device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService('service_id', 'char_id',  'base64firstval')
.then(resp => {
  device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService('service_id', 'char_id', 'base64secondval')
   .then(resp => console.log(resp))
   .catch(err  => console.log(err))
})
.catch(err  => console.log(err))
```

I successfully connect to the device, read from it. My written command comes from the server so i'm 100% its correct. I've encoded it to base64 before sending it.
Both my promises are resolved so both transfers are made to the device but i get no response from the monitor. After a wile i get

```
Disconnection from 'device_id' failed: The specified device has disconnected from 
us.
```

and that is because after 5 seconds of no activity my device disconnects itself.

Comment: To confirm, you are saying the `.then` block never executes for `device.writeCharacteristicWithResponseForService('service_id', 'char_id',  'base64firstval')` ?

Comment: Both write calls are executed, and both promises are resolved. When the device "answers" i should be getting the response in `device.monitorCharacteristicForService`  but nothing happens. The device should either return a response value or raise an error.

Comment: Are you certain the device supports monitoring (aka subscribing) to that characteristic?  Even if it does, how do you know the device is sending a change?